# onClick not triggered when save button is pressed from Testlink

Tags: php, html, mysql, testlink

I am implementing SSO in testlink. I was successful in implementing SSO. But after SSO implementation came across a weird scenario.
After clicking on a test case, click on edit button to edit the test case. Now modify the test case.Now click on 'Save' button. HTML for Save button is given below:

```
<input id="do_update" name="do_update" onclick="show_modified_warning=false; doAction.value='doUpdate'" value="Save" type="submit">
```

But here onclick is not triggered while clicking the Save button. I added an alert in php code and checked. Alert was not displayed.
All other buttons are working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to call you method on the form tag like this:

```
<form onsubmit="return your_function_name();">
...
</form>

Returning false will not submit the form, true will submit!
```

OR 
Try with [onsubmit](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp)

```
<input id="do_update" name="do_update" onsubmit="show_modified_warning=false; doAction.value='doUpdate'" value="Save" type="submit">
```

Comment: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
Ext.util.JSON</doDecode()
 ext-all.js:7
Ext.util.JSON</this.decode</<()
 ext-all.js:7
Ext.ux.requireSessionAndSubmit/<.success()
 ext_extensions.js:272
.handleResponse()
 ext-all.js:7
f()
 ext-base.js:7
m()
 ext-base.js:7
.createCallback/<()